# pip install error when trying to install face_recognition module

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I have a problem when trying to install the face_recognition module using the commandprompt, I used `pip install face_recognition`, but I get a error and I can't resolve it myself. Anyone who can help?

I installed python through Microsoft studios (Python 3.8).
My pip version is 20.2.1

I also tried `pip install face_recognition=1.3.0`

My error is right here:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w68bakhl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\dlib\
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\dlib\setup.py", line 122, in get_cmake_version
        raise RuntimeError("\n*******************************************************************\n" +
    RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _dlib_pybind11
    *******************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoq7h4eo\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w68bakhl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you already installed CMake as the error suggests?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+CMake+must+be+installed+to+build+the+following+extensions

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're missing a library that's required to build your dependencies.

`CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _dlib_pybind11`

Install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) and try installing `face_recognition` again.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don't have the required Libraries

Run `pip install cmake` , and then `pip install dlib`. I guess now you will no longer receive the error...

This will install the requirements.

Comment: I installed cmake, but when I try to install dlib I get a new error.

Comment: @Hunden-DK just try without installing dlib library. Well I am not sure what type of error you are getting...